Searching for records that meet specific conditions
This is my database design:
CREATE TABLE post (
  id INT,
  user_id INT,
  type_id INT
);

I want to get a list of users who wrote posts of types 1 and 2 only. This seems to be working:
select distinct user_id
from post p1
where exists
(
  select 1
  from post p2
  where p1.user_id = p2.user_id
  and type_id = 1
)
and exists
(
  select 1
  from post p2
  where p1.user_id = p2.user_id
  and type_id = 2
)
and not exists
(
  select 1
  from post p2
  where p1.user_id = p2.user_id
  and type_id not in (1,2)
)

I have a feeling this can be done easier. Any ideas?

You can do a GROUP BY. Or use EXCEPT.

Does 'types 1 and 2 only' mean both 1 and 2?

should the output contain the user_id if they had topic_id other than 1 and 2, for example if user_id 1 has post_id 1,2,3 then should the user_id 1 be included?
or it should be exclusively topic 1 and 2

Do you have a user table? You should do, and using that with EXISTS will probably be quickest.

Since you mentioned your query returns correct answer, I compared output of my query against yours and it matches, let me know if you observe any differences, I can edit the answer.
To test the case, I have entered 3 sets of data,

user_id 1 has type 1 and 2
user id 2 has type 1, 2 and 4(so should be excluded from output)
user id 3 has type 1 (should be excluded)

Here is the fiddle
     SELECT user_id
FROM post
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type_id) = 2
  AND SUM(CASE WHEN type_id IN (1, 2) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0;


SUM(CASE WHEN type_id IN (1, 2) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0 is better than: COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN type_id NOT IN (1,2) THEN type END) = 0?

I guess you could do that as well, since filtering is happening on type_id , for me the direct IN clause looks more readable :)
But performance wise you can test if they make a difference

There are quite a few ways to do it with GROUP BY and HAVING.
Here are a few...
SELECT
  user_id
FROM
  post
GROUP BY
  user_id
HAVING
      MIN(type_id) = 1
  AND MAX(type_id) = 2

SELECT
  user_id
FROM
  post
GROUP BY
  user_id
HAVING
      COUNT(DISTINCT type_id) = 2
  AND MAX(CASE WHEN type_id IN (1,2) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0

SELECT
  user_id
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, type_id FROM post) p
GROUP BY
  user_id
HAVING
   SUM(CASE WHEN type_id IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 3 END) = 2

Or using set operators...
SELECT user_id FROM post WHERE type_id = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT user_id FROM post WHERE type_id = 2
EXCEPT
SELECT user_id FROM post WHERE type_id NOT IN (1, 2)


Wouldn't this be better? HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type_id) = 2 AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN type_id NOT IN (1,2) THEN type END) = 0 

The first option it's much easier IMO, I am not sure about the performance though. Which would perform better

@ErgestBasha It would totally depend on your data, and indexing. For cases where there are very few rows per user, I'd expect the first to be quite cheap. For cases where there are many different type_ids per user, the last one may be cheapest. You're always best served to test that for yourself.

another solution using exists operator:
select user_id 
from post p1 
where type_id in(1,2)
  and not exists (
                 select * from post p2
                 where p1.user_id=p2.user_id
                 and p2.type_id  not in (1,2))
group by user_id
having count(distinct type_id)=2;

Hope it helps.
